How to create a bootable ISO file from a .tar.gz on macOS?
I want to use Arch Linux in a VM (I use UTM, which uses QEMU under the hood). Because I'm have an M1 Mac, I need Arch Linux ARM. Unfortunately, there's no installation ISO for Arch Linux ARM like there is for the normal Arch -- there's only a pre-installed file system wrapped in a .tar.gz.
I somehow need UTM to boot that existing installation of Arch ARM, so I need to convert this .tar.gz to a bootable ISO. Is there a way to do this because it seems like mkisofs is not available on Mac.
Perhaps this the wrong approach. I'm not sure if the ISO will be bootable just because there's the linux installation inside it, as far as I know from normal Arch, you need to have a separate partition from where to boot.
Otherwise, the Archlinux ARM webpage  says the files can somehow be directly booted. If I've got something fundamentally wrong here, please let me know, and I will then try to find out more about how EFI boot for linux works, or move my problem to another stack forum.)

What about this site for a ISO?

@DavidAnderson yoooo wth is archboot? Looks useful thank u
